# Issues with Ultralig.ht and making the window minimise instead of close

Tags: c++, c++20

I have been working on a application that works for Windows and Mac, using Ultralig.ht and it has been great but in the function:

```
void MyApp::OnClose(ultralight::Window* window) {
   //app_->Quit();
   window_->Hide();
}
```

I think it is still closing the window of the app. Using window_->Hide(); it is supposed to only hide the window, then in my code for the system tray, I could press Show and it would call window_->Show();, pressing show on the system tray doesn't do anything which is weird. But instead of pressing the close button on the title bar, if I press a hide button on the system tray then press the show button it works fine. It seems to be when it is on the close button. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Check in the documentation of the library how to stop closing a window using `OnClose()`. In each such system there's a special method of doing this. Usually its a method called `ignore()`, `accept()` etc. See for example how it is done in Qt: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcloseevent.html https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-application-example.html#close-event-handler

Comment: And remove the c++20 tag, please.